# Ruby array to string conversion

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have a ruby array like `['12','34','35','231']`.

I want to convert it to a string like `'12','34','35','231'`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 357, accepted):

I'll join the fun with:

```
['12','34','35','231'].join(', ')
# => 12, 34, 35, 231
```

**EDIT:**

```
"'#{['12','34','35','231'].join("', '")}'"
# => '12','34','35','231'
```

Some string interpolation to add the first and last single quote :P

Comment: That results in "12,34,35,231". It's missing the single quotes in the result.

Comment: Okay added some string interpolation to add the first and last single quotes :P

Comment: how to revert this?

Comment: what do you mean revert @zx1986

Comment: @corroded Sorry, I got it. `JSON.parse("[12, 39, 100]")` will return an array.

Answer (score 45):

```
> a = ['12','34','35','231']
> a.map { |i| "'" + i.to_s + "'" }.join(",")
=> "'12','34','35','231'"
```

Comment: Perhaps using `"'#{i}'"` instead.

Comment: don't think map is needed. join should do the trick. see below

Answer (score 36):

try this code  `['12','34','35','231']*","`

will give you result **"12,34,35,231"**

I hope this is the result you, let me know

Comment: I think the OP needs to have the single quote as well.

Answer (score 12):

```
array.map{ |i|  %Q('#{i}') }.join(',')
```

Comment: To quote Mladen, "Perhaps [use] `"'#{i}'"` instead."

Comment: This is the right way to do it, should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
string_arr.map(&:inspect).join(',') # or other separator
```

Comment: This does not produce the correct output - the values needs to be wrapped in single quotes. If this was the desired output then string_arr.join(",") would be the better option.

Comment: Sean, you're wrong. 
Did you run the expression, at least once ??

Comment: It's still wrong. It results in double quotes around the array entries, not single quotes. Plus it relies upon an assumption about the format that "inspect()" prints data, which makes it fragile.

Comment: ['1','2','3'].map { |o| "\'#{o}\'" }.join(',')

Answer (score 7):

I find this way readable and rubyish:

```
add_quotes =- > x{"'#{x}'"}

p  ['12','34','35','231'].map(&add_quotes).join(',') => "'12','34','35','231'"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
> puts "'"+['12','34','35','231']*"','"+"'"
'12','34','35','231'

> puts ['12','34','35','231'].inspect[1...-1].gsub('"',"'")
'12', '34', '35', '231'
```

Answer (score 4):

And yet another variation

```
a = ['12','34','35','231']
a.to_s.gsub(/\"/, '\'').gsub(/[\[\]]/, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
irb(main)> varA
=> {0=>["12", "34", "35", "231"]}
irb(main)> varA = Hash[*ex.collect{|a,b| [a,b.join(",")]}.flatten]
...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
irb(main):027:0> puts ['12','34','35','231'].inspect.to_s[1..-2].gsub('"', "'")
'12', '34', '35', '231'
=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some functional programming approach, transforming data:

`['12','34','35','231'].map{|i| "'#{i}'"}.join(",")`

Answer (score 2):

suppose your array :

```
arr=["1","2","3","4"]
```

Method to convert array to string:

```
Array_name.join(",")
```

Example:

```
arr.join(",")
```

Result:

```
"'1','2','3','4'"
```

Answer (score -6):

`array.inspect.inspect.gsub(/\[|\]/, "")` could do the trick