# Can't return strings from arrays - pig latin - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I am trying to do a Pig Latin Kata on Codewars and I'm really struggling to return the strings in the array as a string.

Not sure where I'm going wrong - any help would be really appreciated.

```
def pig_it text
  text.split.map.each { |word| word.chars.rotate(1).join+"ay"}
end

text = 'Pig latin is cool'

pig_it(text)
```

It returns the array and the pig latin translation works fine. Cannot figure out how to return it as a string. 
`["igPay", "atinlay", "siay", "oolcay"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500814/ruby-array-to-string-conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the `#each` call from `text.split.map.each { |word| word.chars.rotate(1).join+"ay"}`. The map call takes a block as argument. There is no point of having that `#each` call.
2. You need another `#join` after the `#map` That will, for instance, transform `["hello", "world"]` into `"hello world"`.

And then you'll have:

```
def pig_it(text)
  text.split.map { |word| word.chars.rotate(1).join + "ay" }.join(" ")
end

text = "Pig latin is cool"
pig_it(text)
#=> "igPay atinlay siay oolcay"
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done all the hard work and got an array of strings you want to join together, now you just need to join them:

```
def pig_it text
  text.split.map.each { |word| word.chars.rotate(1).join+"ay"}.join(' ')
end

text = 'Pig latin is cool'

pig_it(text)
=> "igPay atinlay siay oolcay"
```

Whatever argument you feed into join will be the character used inbetween array elements

Comment: @david No point - just got left behind when I added in the {}